# Sharepoint Infopath View to PDF

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, view, sp-online

I was tasked with trying to figure out wether CSOM code can be written in order to extract a view from an Infopath form and convert that view to PDF.

At the moment, i have built:

1. a simple Sharepoint List,
2. added an infopath form for adding new items and
3. created another infopath view which simply has a "Hello World" message (no dynamic content).

I am currently looking into ways of how can i access the particular view using CSOM code.

Is that even possible, accessing the Infopath View instead of the ListItem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, i came to the point that the above cannot be done programmatically, although a user that has opened a list item and having the infopath form rendered on his screen, can press Ctrl + P and print a pdf document.

The above was tested with Google Chrome.